# MongoDB get ArrayFilters reference to update value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I recently started using MongoDB and I'm trying to update a few properties from a document but not being able to get the object reference to update a value.

Please consider the following data:

```
const data = {
 weekplanId: 'someid',
 days: [
  {label: 'Monday', cost: 20, comment: "some comment" },
  {label: 'Tuesday', cost: 40, comment: "..." }
 ]
}

const update = await weekplan.updateOne(
    {
      _id: new ObjectId(data.weekplanId),
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "weekdays.$[i].cost": data.days.$[i].cost,
        "weekdays.$[i].comment": data.days.$[i].comment,
        "weekdays.$[i].date": new Date(),
        "weekdays.$[i].someproperty": "something",
      }
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          "i.label": {
            $in: data.days.map(p => p.label),
          },
        }]
    }
  );
```

How can I reference the array object to set the property value?
I know `data.days.$[i].cost` and `data.days.$[i].comment` are wrong, they are just an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Setting the `date` and `someproperty` works as expected, since the values are not dependent on the source data.

I would like to try to do this without using JS.

Is arrayFilters even appropriate for this? I'd appreciate some guidance as to where to look at.

Thanks in advance!

**###EDIT:**

Expected output:

```
 "_id": {"someid"},
 "weekdays": [
    {
        "day": "Monday",
        "cost": 20,
        "comment": "some comment",
        "date": 2021-08-01T19:51:45.057Z
        "someproperty": "something"
    },
    {
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "cost": 40,
        "comment": "...",
        "date": 2021-08-01T19:51:45.057Z
        "someproperty": "something"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
]
```

The rest of the week days (Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) would remain untouched on this update.

Comment: Not sure exactly why you want to do this as it's basically `x=x`. however to answer you, you can't with the normal update operators. they can't access existing document values within the update operation.
what you want to use in this case is pipelined updates:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: It's not clear what your trying to do if you can elaborate what do you want exactly

Comment: @TomSlabbaert thanks, I'll definetly take a look into that.

Comment: @Zein I edited the post and added the expected output, I hope its more clear now

Answer (score 0):

In that example code `data.days.$[i].cost` is evaluated on the client side, before the query is submitted, so whatever value (or lack thereof) that is has will be assigned to the corresponding field of the `$set` object when the server receives it.

The `data` object will not be sent to the server with the query, so even if it were able to do array lookup on input values, the input value would not be there.

The way to accomplish this is to iterate the array on the client side, and programmatically build the update query.  Perhaps something like:

```
let labelChar = 105;
let setOps = {};
let filters = {};
data.days.forEach( function(day) {
  let char = String.fromCharCode(labelChar++);
  setOps['weekdays.$[' + char + '].cost'] = day.cost;
  setOps['weekdays.$[' + char + '].comment'] = day.comment;
  setOps['weekdays.$[' + char + '].date'] = new Date();
  setOps['weekdays.$[' + char + '].someproperty'] = "something";
  let filterObj = {};
  filterObj[char + '.label'] = day.label;
  filters.push(filterObj);
});
const update = await weekplan.updateOne(
    {
      _id: new ObjectId(data.weekplanId),
    },
    {
      $set: setOps
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: filters
    }
  );
```

For the provided sample input, this will give the update:

```
.updateOne(
    {
      _id: new ObjectId(data.weekplanId),
    },
    {
      $set: {
             'weekdays.$[i].cost': 20,
             'weekdays.$[i].comment': 'some comment',
             'weekdays.$[i].date': ISODate(),
             'weekdays.$[i].someproperty': 'something',
             'weekdays.$[j].cost': 40,
             'weekdays.$[j].comment': '...',
             'weekdays.$[j].date': ISODate(),
             'weekdays.$[j].someproperty': 'something'
            }
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
                     {'i.label': 'Monday'}, 
                     {'j.label': 'Tuesday'}
                    ]
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My explanation was probably not good enough, I edited the post with the expected output. I know that the `data.days.$[i].cost` is completely wrong, I used it as an example of what I wanted (probably bad idea to put it like that). I just don't know how to "grab" the value "20" for example, and use it on the update operation.

Comment: That's exactly what this code does.  You have to grab the values from the array on the client side, before sending the request to the server, because the array is not available on the server side.